# Is there a list of input variables?

Tags: ffmpeg

There is an article that says you can scale a video to be a multiple or fraction of the input size like this:

```
-vf "scale=iw/2:ih/2" to scale by half
```

Are there any other symbols for input variables in addition to `iw` and `ih`?

I've done multiple web searches and forum searches and I can't find anything that says what list of input values there are that are like `ih` and `iw`.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Video Production! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for ffmpeg is at http://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

`scale` here refers to the scale filter, whose documentation is at http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1

The list of variables available in this filter is listed at the bottom of the [Options](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Options-1) section.

Comment: I did try the documentation, but it was difficult to find the values. Are the values for scaling the only variables of this kind?  I was hoping for one that would give the frame rate of the video being read, or the bit rates of the video and audio of the file being read.

Comment: The variables available in a filter are specific to it. By convention, filters will use similar names for a parameter. But you need to consult an filter's doc for that info.